# Frankenstein's Repulsion towards his Monster

Tags: character-analysis, frankenstein, mary-shelley

Throughout the novel, Victor Frankenstein is horrified at the fact that he created his monster. However, he does not discuss any emotional or moral reservations towards the act of creating the monster and the monster itself. In fact, when he is talking with the monster in the Alps he says that

> "His words had a strange effect upon me. I compassionated him and sometimes felt a wish to console him, but when I looked upon him, when I saw the filthy mass that moved and talked, my heart sickened and my feelings were altered to those of horror and hatred."

revealing that the disgust seems purely physical. Furthermore, to me it seems that Frankenstein cannot have hated his monster solely for the murders it committed since he hated the monster the moment he created it. This makes it seem that the hatred is rather shallow and unrealistic. Of course, Frankenstein may have felt disgust for the creature, however, to call something abhorrent despite the fact that it showed kindness and compassion seems to extreme of a reaction. Is there anything about the culture of the time period that explains this or did they have a different world view that makes this hatred less unrealistic?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I think Frankinstein is so freaked out when the monster first comes to life that he runs away.

Comment: Great question! This should lead to some very interesting analysis and different takes on the novel and its morals.